# Solutions for working on and testing deep or guarded routes/features

Tags: angular, architecture, development-environment

A common problem I encounter working on front end work (targetting my work with Angular with this particular question but broader answers are welcomed!) is how to solve some of the workflow issues that stem from working on features or parts of the application that are cumbersome to get to.

For example, I'm currently working on a particular page or route of an Angular application. The development environment is set up, I'm running a nodejs server and the angular app locally. The page I'm working on requires me to sign in to the app, navigate to my profile, start a multi-step form and finally get to page 8 of the form.

This process has to be repeated every time I make some change in the code and I want to see the results, which slows down progress tremendously.

Are there best practices/architectural suggestion/what have you, when it comes to structuring the application so that it's easy to test pages/feature/components like this?

Right now what I've been doing is creating a test route that I populate with the current component/directive/etc that I'm working on, allowing me to iterate on it much more quickly. But the problem comes back when I'm compositing the page and need to see the results there.

I guess the ideal solution would be a way to structure a route so that it can be easily called, routed to on startup, passed the required data (either mocked or from a development API) and in that way be able to directly navigate to it as soon as I make a change to the codebase.

Can this be achieved, and how?